# Is there a 1D Lorentzian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In Nakahara (Theorem 7.4, Pg 291) we have for an $r$-form on an $m$-dimensional manifold $$ * *\omega = (-1)^{r(m-r)}\omega$$ when Riemannian and $$ * *\omega = (-1)^{1+r(m-r)}\omega$$ when Lorentzian. So, for $m = 1$, it is possible to have $$ * * = -1$$ for a $0$-form in $1D$ Lorentizan manifold. Hence, my question. Does $1D$ Lorentizian manifold makes sense?

Comment: Guessing from the title $m$ should be one (not zero). This manifold carries $0$-forms and $1$-forms and  $dx$ is a volume form. Then $*dx=1$ and $**dx=dx\,.$

Comment: As far as I know Lorentzian manifolds are pseudo-Riemannian manifolds whose metric has signature $(1,n-1)$ (the same of a Minkowski space). If $n=1$ there's no room for a non-definite metric, so you basically find a Riemannian manifold

Comment: @KurtG. Oh yes.

Comment: @Fredrico Does $(n-1, 1)$ count as pseudo-Riemannian?

Comment: Don't think so. A pseudo Riemannian MF should allow for timelike, lightlike *and* spacelike curves. Or, as Federico T put it: for a non-definite metric. It is a bit similar to symplectic MFs who need to be evendimensional.

Comment: At a purely formal level, you could define a 1d Lorentzian manifold as a 1-manifold with a negative definite metric tensor, and if you define the Hodge star and other such metric-dependent objects correctly then the signs should work out. It's very much a trivial case, but it can work as a notion of "relativity in discrete space and continuous time".